# Replace 'Reveal All' button with 'Reveal Less' onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I am currently using a 'Reveal All' button on a table to display all the table entries:

http://jsfiddle.net/SCpgC/

However, I was wondering, is there a way I can switch 'Reveal All' to display 'Reveal Less' when clicked, so the user can return to the previous view?

Here is the current JavaScript I am using:

```
var numShown = 2; // Initial rows shown & index

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Hide rows and add clickable div

        $('table').find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end().after('<div class="more">Reveal All</div>');

        $('.more').click(function() {
            var numRows = $(this).prev().find('tr').show();
            $(this).remove();
        })
    });
```

Many thanks for any pointers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work both ways... if **reveal all** it **shows the div** and if **reveal less** it **hides the div**

try this

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/SCpgC/1/)

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("show")) {
        var numRows = $(this).prev().find('tr').show();
        $(this).text('Reveal Less');
        $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    }
    else {
        $(this).prev().find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide();
        $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
        $(this).text('Reveal All');
    }
});
```

and using some effects `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

[fiddel with effect](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/SCpgC/3/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var numShown = 2; // Initial rows shown & index
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide rows and add clickable div
    $('table').find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end().after('<div class="more">Reveal All</div>');
    $('.more').on('click',function() {
        if ($(this).text()=="Reveal All") {
         $(this).prev().find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').show();
            $(this).text("Reveal less");
        } else {
           $(this).prev().find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide();
            $(this).text("Reveal All");
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SCpgC/4/

UPDATE: this should return the table to the exact previous status (won't hide everything). Also added .on() method instead of .click()

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work:

```
var numShown = 2; // Initial rows shown & index
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide rows and add clickable div
    $('table').find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end().after('<div class="more">Reveal All</div>');
    $('.more').click(function() {
        if ($(this).text()=="Reveal All") {
            $('table').find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').show();
            $(this).text("Reveal less");
        } else {
            $('table').find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide();
            $(this).text("Reveal All");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 'Reveal Less' seems to remove ALL the table rows. I'd prefer if it reverted back to the `numShown` value. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
var numShown = 2; // Initial rows shown & index
var hideText = 'Hide all';
var revealText = 'Reveal all';

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide rows and add clickable div

    $('table').find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end().after('<div class="more">' + revealText + '</div>');
    var numRows;
    $('.more').toggle(function() {
        numRows = $(this).prev().find('tr').show();
        $(this).text(hideText);
    }, function() {
        numRows = $(this).prev().find('tr').hide();
        $(this).text(revealText);
    });
});
```

Edit: Sorry, forgot that toggle doesn't work with live/on